# Using a VoIP router behind a DrayTek 2760 router

Tags: wireless-router, voip, sip, draytek

I'm struggling with the following problem:

I use a DrayTek Vigor 2760 as router 1 to access internet by using a VDSL line. The DrayTek behaves as a Modem and DHCP server with IP 192.168.1.1. My second router is a TP-Link VR200v with disabled DHCP server and IP 192.168.1.2. It's set to "Wireless router mode". The VR200v includes VOIP functionality that I want to use - but it does not connect so I cannot use my DECT phone.

I configured the DrayTek to open UDP port 5060 to my secondary router 192.168.1.2. And it's configured to SIP ALG enabled. VoIP and DECT still does not work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Sven

Comment: Try disabling SIP ALG. See my answer [Why SIP-ALG in routers and modems?](//superuser.com/a/1195490)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing who your SIP provider is and how their registration works it is difficult to troubleshoot this. If the DECT phone is a SIP VoIP phone, then you will need to statically assign the phone on the subnet with the gateway address being that of your TP-Link router, 192.168.1.2. You should also disable SIP ALG in the TP-Link if the registration is not making it through the device. SIP ALG often causes more problems then it resolves. This is the number one cause of VoIP issues in my experience as a VoIP engineer. If these suggestions do not resolve the issue I would suggest taking a packet capture off the LAN and WAN while restarting the phone. Make sure the REGISTER packets headers are going to the correct IP/domain of your SIP provider and that the header packets are not being manipulated by the TP-Link.

Comment: Hi Killean, thanks for your reply. My SIP provider is Deutsche Telekom in Germany, I'm using VDSL 50. I already contacted TP-Link support but their support is very limited because they say that the router is at the end-of-life. It doesn't seem that they will resolve this issue.